# Difference between ( $value == 1 ) and ( $value == '1' )

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to know the difference between

```
if($value == 1){
  //code
}
```

and

```
if($value == '1'){
  //code
}
```

$value is integer which I select from database(MySQL).
Of course, I insert it into database as Interger.

Either method works correctly for the moment, which is the more accurate way?

Thanks.

Comment: [Loose typing comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most correct way is:

```
if($value === '1')
```

This is because all (non-NULL) values in MySQL are returned as strings, as this prevents loss of accuracy for high-precision storage, such as `BIGINT` being sent to a 32-bit process, or fixed-point real numbers.

However, you are most likely to encounter:

```
if($value == 1)
```

Because really, who cares?

Answer (score 1):

> more accurate way

It's good habit to compare with using right type, even with loose typing languages like PHP as this would simply save you from troubles at some time in future. So if your `$value` is string, compare with string (`... == '1'`). If you know it is i.e. integer, do `... == 1`.

See this chapter of PHP docs: [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and [String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Answer (score 1):

`if($value == 1){
  //code
}`

here you just compare the value to a number

`if($value == '1'){
  //code
}`

here you just compare the value to an String

if you going use this one
I suggest you change the 1 to an name better than a number

Answer (score 0):

```
$value == 1
```

Compares `$value` with the [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) `1`.

```
$value == '1'
```

Compares `$value` with the [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) `1`.

If `$value`, as you say, contains an integer, and it's value is `1` as well, both comparisons will evaluate to `true`.

This is because, when using `==`, you are performing a [loose comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). This means that the types don't have to be the same. `'1' == 1` will therefore return `true`, even though `'1'` is a string and `1` is an integer. `'1' == true` and `1 == true` will return `true` as well. This is because `1`, `'1'`, and `true` are all considered equal.

However, using the `===` operator, you can enforce strict comparison. In that case, the types **will** have to be the same. `'1' === 1` will return `false`, because `'1'` is a string and `1` is an integer. The same goes for `'1' === true` and `1 === true`.

Since the value is stored in your database as an integer, I'd recommend using

```
if ($value == 1) {
    //code
}
```

Only if you need to be sure that `$value` is an integer, and not something else, use:

```
if ($value === 1) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($value == 1){
  //code
}
```

this would be more appropriate because the $value coming from the DB is a integer value.

But even the following wud work. But this is how we represent a string in php.

```
if($value == '1'){
    //code
}
```

Here the type casting on the string to integer happens automatically. So both the conditions will be true.

Answer (score 0):

Question is somewhat unclear. Do we talk about commands going to SQL server? Otherwise this question has nothing to do with MySQL. Therefore I assume context here is SQL injection protection.

If something goes to MySQL, then it is safer to enclose it between quotes. For example

URL foorbar?ID=1

is safer to process as:

```
<?php $query="SELECT * FROM something WHERE ID='".mysql_escape($ID)."'" ?>
```

than

```
<?php $query="SELECT * FROM something WHERE ID=".mysql_escape($ID) ?>
```

because latter case does not protect for constructs like `123 OR 1=1` which leads to overload of SQL server if table has lot of data in it. `'123 OR 1=1'` will be used as number and understood as 123 and does not cause problems.